# Why is the function $f(x) = e^x$ not a rational function?

Tags: functions, polynomials, rational-numbers, rational-functions

This is probably a misunderstanding of how e works on my part, but I figured that since $e^x$ is a polynomial and $f(x)$ can be rewritten as $(e^x)/1$ that it was rational, but that turned out to be incorrect. Can someone explain where my error came from?

Comment: $e^x$ is **not** a polynomial though.

Comment: $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^ \infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ can be represented as a power series with infinitely many terms, but not a polynomial (which must have finitely many terms)

Comment: A rational function can't have limits the way $e^x$ has when $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, a polynomial is a sum of nonnegative integer powers of a variable. In $e*x$ the variable is in the exponent, so that's not a polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

$e^x$ is not a polynomial. The power series defining it involves infinitely many terms.

However, a priori this doesn't rule out the possibility that $e^x$ could be written as a rational function in some more complicated way. So here is a proof of that. Any non-constant rational function $f(z) = \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ takes on the value either $0$ or $\infty$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$, given by a root of either the numerator or denominator. But $e^z \neq 0, \infty$ for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$. (Many other proofs could also be given here.)

Answer (score 2):

to see that $e^{x}$ is not polynomial,use the fact that polynomials are characterized by the fact that their $n$-derivative is identically zero, for some n,and this is not the case for $e^{x}$ .to see that $e^{x}$  is not a rational function, one can use the fact that the limits of any rational function at $\pm \infty$ are both either zero, a constant or $\pm \infty $ but for $e^{x}$  one limit is zero, while the other is $+\infty$.